# Angular and ngMessages

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form with an error field.  Code is as follows:

```html
<form name="myform" ng-submit="submit">
  <input name="text" ng-model="username" required>
  <div ng-messages="myform.username.$error">
    <div  ng-message="required">Field is required</div>
    <div ng-message="has_spaces">Field must not contain spaces</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Is my logic of how ngMessages work correct? I tried setting "has_spaces" after the form is submitted but nothing works.

Comment: I think your problem simply is that you need to access the form field (the username input) by its `name` instead of the `ng-model` identifier. Other than that, your logic appears to be correct

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet is correct, except you need to access the form element for which you want to get errors by its `name` attribute and **not** the value of `ng-model`. I.e., instead of accessing `myform.username.$error`, you should access `myform.text.$error`. This snippet should do the job:

```html
<form name="myform" ng-submit="submit">
  <input name="text" ng-model="username" required>
  <div ng-messages="myform.text.$error">
    <div  ng-message="required">Field is required</div>
    <div ng-message="has_spaces">Field must not contain spaces</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

1. you're referencing the model rather than the name of the input field itself in ng-messages.
2. You didn't define an input type. make type="text"
3. Renamed the input name to username, however in the model itself you should store it to an object IMO

**I've corrected it below, try this instead**

```
<form name="myform" ng-submit="submit">
  <input name="username" type="text" ng-model="user.name" required>
  <div ng-messages="myform.username.$error">
    <div  ng-message="required">Field is required</div>
    <div ng-message="has_spaces">Field must not contain spaces</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where does "usernamename" come from?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-message, ng-maxlength, ng-minlength` or any kind of validation in angular it use the name attribute instead of ng-model. So in your code you must use `ng-messages = "myform.text.$error"`.